# Javascript not working after reloading the page with a href = '#'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I have a button on my page that is supposed to redirect to reload the home page. The problem is that my javascript does not properly works anymore after redirecting to '#'.

I have my javascript wrapped in window.onload = function() {}

Is there a different way to redirect to the home page or is there a way to prevent this error from occurring.

Comment: Could you please provide the piece of code that doesn't work?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not a specific piece that is not working, javascript buttons are not generated properly, the click events on my buttons are not working etc. etc.

Comment: changing hash does not load the page. Sounds like you should be doing something different. What is the code doing that you want to load again?

Answer (score 1):

Changing only the hash part of the URL does not trigger a reload of the page and, hence, does not execute `window.onload` again. You may need to trigger the function manually, when the `a` tag is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting to '#' would not actually reload the home page, it is usually used to navigate to a specific `id` tag on the page. If your button is just using an href to navigate to '#' eg `href="#"` then you could switch it out with `.` eg `href="."`. The `.` refers to the current directory, and that would actually reload the page and trigger the `window.onload`.